# How to setup SMTP server for a node js application to send receive mails?

Tags: node.js, email, smtp

I am creating a node js application, where I required to send and receive the email.
I wanted to create a custom email like myname@mycompany.com for every user of this web app.
How to create this programmatically using the SMTP Server?

also wanted to send and receive email through the SMTP server.
any suggestion for SMTP server provider to achieve this programmatically?

Comment: I recommend starting with Postfix and Dovecot. Then add MySQL or LDAP to automate new users. I would not recommend this project unless you are well funded and know what you are doing with email server management. We are not talking about one app, we are talking about a dozen apps working together as a system.

Answer (score 10):

### tldr

If you want your app to be self-contained it needs to function as an SMTP client to send email directly to recipients, and as an SMTP server to receive email. If you want to use a provider [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) is a solid offering.

### You might be misunderstanding SMTP

In SMTP, the client (the one who initiates the connection) is always the email sender and the server is always the recipient. SMTP gets used in 2 contexts, but fundamentally it's the same thing going on, just with and without requiring authentication.

- The first is when users send email to their email provider. For example: I, Alice, use Gmail. I want to send an email to bob@yahoo.com. I start by sending the email to Gmail via SMTP. Gmail's SMTP server is `smtp.gmail.com`. `smtp.gmail.com` requires authentication. I authenticate using my Gmail username and password. Once authenticated I am allowed to send email from alice@gmail.com to anyone.
- The second is when a server wants to send email to another server. For example: I'm Gmail. One of my users, Alice, just submitted an email to bob@yahoo.com. I need to send that message to the mail servers responsible for the yahoo.com domain, so I look at the `MX` records for yahoo.com. I see that yahoo.com has 3 mail servers listed: `mta5.am0.yahoodns.net`, `mta6.am0.yahoodns.net`, and `mta7.am0.yahoodns.net`. I am supposed to try the one with the lowest `priority` value first, but all 3 have a `priority` of 1, so I just pick one at random. I open an SMTP connection to `mta7.am0.yahoodns.net`. This server does not require authentication. I am allowed to send email from anyone to anyone@yahoo.com.

SMTP does not have commands to create an account. In fact, SMTP can operate without accounts at all, just like HTTP can operate without a directory of files to serve.

As far as SMTP is concerned the only way to receive mail is to be the SMTP server listening on port 25 for the address listed in the `MX` record for mycompany.com. There is no way to connect to another SMTP server and ask "give me all the email for myname@mycompany.com". That is what POP and IMAP are for.

### How to do what you want

You have 2 separate problems. You need to be able to send mail and you need to be able to receive mail.

- Sending

  - Whenever you need to email foo@bar.com, you could look up the `MX` records for bar.com, open an SMTP connection to that server, and deliver the message directly. The main problem with this is trying not to wind up in people's spam folder. There are several tricks to this, but that is a whole subject of it's own.
  - You could use an intermediate SMTP server that you pay someone else to operate. SendGrid and MailGun are 2 examples here. Just like when Alice connected to `smtp.gmail.com`, you could connect to SendGrid's SMTP server. You would authenticate with them, but unlike with Alice who could only send from alice@gmail.com to anyone, you would be allowed to send email from anyone@mycompany.com to anyone. SendGrid would take care of making sure your emails don't wind up in people's spam.
  - You could use some other non-SMTP API to send email. [Amazon SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) for example.
- Receiving

  - You could operate an SMTP server. It could even be built in to your node app if you wanted. You would just need to make sure your server was listening on port 25, and that 1st `MX` record (the one with the lowest priority) for mycompany.com pointed to that server. This lets you react the second you get an email. You might get a lot of spam doing this, so be ready for that.
  - You could pay someone to operate an SMTP server for you, and have them dump the email they get into a mailbox accessible via POP or IMAP. You would add an `MX` record for mycompany.com pointing to the company's SMTP server. You would add accounts using their API. You would poll for new email via POP or IMAP (IMAP supports notifications, but it is a more complex protocol).
  - Amazon SES also supports receiving email.

Comment: I did misunderstand the SMTP but thank you for the clarification. However, I want my application to be like a mail server system (a small Gmail like app). As soon as one signup on my app portal, I should be able to create a mail for him e.g. name@mycompany.com. this user can send/receive/reply and forward the emails to anyone through the app. So AFAIK, I need a mail server (maybe like Zimbra or iRedMail), which can be used through REST API. another thing is mail domain names based on which I will be creating new emails for signed-up users. any suggestion for such mail server?